# EmberJS: Accessing child controller functionality in parent

Tags: ember.js

This may be more of a structure question but the heading is my current issue.

I have the following basic app:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('numbers', {
        path: '/'
    });
    this.resource('users');

});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});

App.NumbersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.findAll('number');
    }
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    numbers: DS.hasMany('number', {
        async: true
    })
});

App.Number = DS.Model.extend({
    value: DS.attr('number'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});


App.NumbersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    total: function () {
        var total = 0;
        this.forEach(function (number) {
            total += parseFloat(number.get('value'));
        });
        return total;
    }.property()
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bob',
    numbers: [100, 101]
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Fred',
    numbers: [102]
}];

App.Number.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 100,
    value: 25,
    user: 1
}, {
    id: 101,
    value: 15,
    user: 1
}, {
    id: 102,
    value: 60,
    user: 2
}];
```

Working example with templates is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sweetrollAU/9DuR3/

The example shows a relationship between users and numbers. The first page is a list of all numbers in the app, their related user and a total of all numbers. The Users link shows the same content but each user should show its own subtotal for the numbers it has.

My question is basically, how can I access the NumbersController method 'total' in my UsersController? Should I be accessing this method or do I have the structure incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Both answers were more than sufficient but have chosen the second for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kingpin2k's answer seems sufficient, but here's another way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9DuR3/3/

What happens here is that the numbers are rendered again, for each users, but this time with a different template. Namely the one between the `{{render}}` tags. The `NumbersController` is provided with the `user.numbers` collection, instead of the complete numbers collection.

Also it's important to specify on which properties the `total` function dependent is (`.property('@each.value')`).

Answer (score 2):

In your case they are similar logic, but they ultimately come from different data sources.  You can still create a `Mixin` that can help you share the code amongst different Ember objects.

```
App.AddNumberMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
    sumNumbers: function(arr){
      var total = 0;
      arr.forEach(function (number) {
          total += parseFloat(number.get('value'));
      });
      return total; 
    }
});

App.UserController  = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.AddNumberMixin, {
    total: function () {
        return this.sumNumbers(this.get('numbers'));
    }.property('numbers.@each.value')
});

App.NumbersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.AddNumberMixin, {
    total: function () {
        return this.sumNumbers(this);
    }.property('@each.value')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9DuR3/2/